# Lombok String Array Property

Tags: java, spring, lombok

Is there away to use an array value from a JSON object as a lombok value. For example the body

```
{
"associatedCompanyIds": [                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      332510120384                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    ]
}
```

As

```
@lombok.value
private static class Payload{
    private List<String> associatedCompanyIds; 
}
```

I know this won't work, but I'm trying to do something similar to this so that I can extract that first value of the array.

Answer (score 1):

This works almost out of the box. The only thing you have to do is to advise lombok to generate a `@java.beans.ConstructorProperties` annotation, so that Jackson knows which constructor parameter to use for which JSON value.
Simply create a `lombok.config` in your project root folder with this content:

```
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties = true 
config.stopBubbling = true
```

The drawback is that Jackson will pass an `ArrayList`, which is mutable. So if you want a truely immutable value class, you have to use lombok's `@Builder` with `@Singular`:

```
@Builder(setterPrefix = "with")
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Payload.PayloadBuilder.class)
@Value
public class Payload {
    @Singular
    private List<String> associatedCompanyIds;
}
```

You don't even need the `lombok.config` with this approach, but you need at least lombok v1.18.12 (because of the `setterPrefix`).